# Double hash values in Perl

Tags: perl, hash

When using hashes, Perl has the very handy `values` keyword to handle only the values of the hash.

Say I have a double hash, i.e. something created like this:

```
my %dh = map { {$_->{id1}}{$_->{id2}} => $_ } @arr;
```

Then `values %dh` returns an array of hashes. To access the values I would need something like this:

```
for my $key1 (keys %dh) {
    for my $val (values %{ $dh{$key1} }) {
        # stuff...
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to do this, avoiding `for` cycles? Something like `values %{ values %dh }`.

Also, sorry for the poor syntax, I'm quite new to Perl.

Comment: `map` and `keys` I guess, but I don't have the tuits to build a test case right now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `map` again to extract it. Don't be under any illusions though - it's still looping. It might be more elegant though:

```
for my $val ( map { values %$_ } values %dh ) {
    #do stuff
}
```

This is more or less doing the same thing though - it's flattening your hash - getting the `values` from `%dh` - which will be a list of hash-refs - and then pulling the `values` out of those. (I think this should do it,  but without test data I can't tell you for sure).

Note - the return order from `values` is undefined, so you'll get them in a randomish order. You can control ordering via `keys` (and maybe `sort`) if you're so inclined.

What `map` does is simply evaluate a code block, and returns the results as a list. That's why `map { $_ => 1 } qw ( one two three )` works - it's actually returning a pair of values, which *when you assign it to a hash* is treated as key-value pairs.

```
use Data::Dumper;

my @stuff = map { $_ => 1 } qw ( one two three );
print Dumper \@stuff;
my %hash = map { $_ => 1 } qw ( one two three ); 
print Dumper \%hash;
```

So - `map` is returning 2 values here, which you *could* write as:

```
my @stuff = map { $_,  1 } qw ( one two three );
```

Because of course, `=>` is really just a comma (with some extra functionality around quoting).

So when doing a dereference of an array, you can do the same - `values` returns a list of values from each element in the `map`.

For the sake of clarity:

```
use Data::Dumper;
my @stuff = ( [ 1, 2, 3 ], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9] );
print Dumper \@stuff;
my @newstuff = map { @$_ } @stuff; 
print Dumper \@newstuff;
```

Is doing essentially the same thing - traversing each of the hash references in `@stuff` (because that's how multi-dimensional arrays are implemented in `perl`) and then 'unpacks' them, returning the results.

Comment: .. the beef being here that you can return multiple values from the code block passed to map and they will be flattened into one stream of values from map.